What is the latin translation for "enemy of all tyrants"
Im not looking for the usual "sic semper tyrannis"
I'm wondering if "hostis tyrannis generis" is a more literal translation for enemy of all tyrants.
Tyia

No, hostis tyrannis generis does not mean what you want. (It means enemy to the tyrants of the clan, or something close to that.)
You want hostis tyrannis omnibus (enemy to all tyrants) or hostis tyrannorum omnium (enemy of all tyrants).
You might also want to consider inimicus (masculine) or inimica (feminine) as a replacement for hostis if you are talking about a personal opposition to or hatred of tyrants, rather than a military opponent to tyrants.
